# All Tags not replicating from SOAP Endpoint while creating REST Service in WSO2 API-Manager

Tags: rest, soap, wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am trying to create a REST Endpoint from a SOAP Endpoint using WSO2 API Manager(v3.2.0).
Steps are

1. Launch API Manager
2. Create API > I have a SOAP Endpoint
3. Implementation Type : Generate REST APIs, Input Type : WSDL URL
4. I enter the WSDL URL and system validates it.
5. I enter the Name of the API, context, version, endpoint URL and select the Business Plan and click on CREATE.
6. API is created. Now I click on Resources and a specific post method e.g., createContract. In the in-mediation file, all xml tags present in the SOAP endpoint is not reflected properly.

I have tried to add these tags manually as well but it does not reflect in the REST API.

Kindly help!

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-07-29 09:28:14,972]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt.handlers.DefaultKeyValidationHandler} - org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt.handlers.DefaultKeyValidationHandler Initialised
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-07-29 09:28:15,120] ERROR {org.apache.synapse.mediators.bsf.ScriptMediator} - {api:admin--FCUBSDEService:v1} The script engine returned an error executing the inlined js script function mediate com.sun.phobos.script.util.ExtendedScriptException: org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: ReferenceError: "Jrnl" is not defined. (<Unknown Source>#3) in <Unknown Source> at line number 3
    at com.sun.phobos.script.javascript.RhinoCompiledScript.eval(RhinoCompiledScript.java:68)
    at java.scripting/javax.script.CompiledScript.eval(CompiledScript.java:89)
```

Comment: What is the API Manager version you are using? Is it possible to share the WSDL content?

Comment: I am using API Manager v3.2.0 and I believe its the same with v4.0.0. WSDL content is placed here for reference - [link] https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yrvXV_3i7UlskPSdB72btH9d8t3ccYH4/view

Comment: The one shared in the drive doesn't seem to be a valid WSDL. If you are not able to attach the complete WSDL you can post the element definition (probably a complex type definition) for which the attributes are missing.

Comment: Another way to troubleshoot is, you can check the generated swagger definition and see if it has all the attributes for the particular swagger model

Comment: Hi, Apologies for the last wsdl error. Please find the updated URL present here. The WSDL -  [link] (https://drive.google.com/file/d/130cWUomhmOfivaXkj7Ku5Gzsa3kQ6rV9/view?usp=sharing) and the Swagger.yaml present here [link] (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YLSsnlUYP0HK2mG5SKkBgPHE-I63fd8s/view?usp=sharing) .

Comment: In addition, I have manually added the properties and type in the API Definition and now it shows in the request json, but it is failing with the below error.   {Debugs added in the editor section}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                I could see there is an error Unknown Source at Line number 3. Which file is it referring to? and where can i maintain this source. Request you to kindly help.